# Finding dimension of a submodule

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, modules, dimension-theory-algebra

Let     $G= (\mathbb{C}^3, A)$ be the $\mathbb C[x]$-module given by 
$$
       A=\left( \begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}\right).
$$
For a vector $v ∈ \mathbb C^3$ let $L(v) := \{f(x)v \mid f ∈ \mathbb C[x]\}$ be the submodule of $G$ generated by $v$.

I'm trying to find all $v$ such that $\dim L(v)=3$.

I've found that the eigenspace of $A$ is $\mathbb{C}e_1$, not really sure what to do next

Comment: You should edit your question to explain better what you ask. Do you mean that $C$ is the field $\mathbb{C}$ and the module structure is obtained by letting $x$ act as $A$? If so, write this explicitly.

Comment: @levap Yes I mean C to be the complex field. I'm not sure about the module structure, this is how the question was worded in the book

Comment: I think this is the only interpretation that makes sense (that is, $xv = Av$ for $v \in \mathbb{C}^3$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $A$ is nilpotent (satisfying $A^3 = 0$). Thus,

$$ L(v) = \mathrm{span} \{ v, Av, A^2v \}. $$

Check that if $A^2v \neq 0$, then the set $\{ v, Av, A^2v \}$ is linearly independent (this is a general useful property for a sequence of vectors of the form $(v, Av, \ldots, A^kv)$ where $A^{k+1}v = 0$ which comes in handy when analyzing nilpotent matrices). Thus, $L(v) = \mathbb{C}^3$ if and only if $A^2v  \neq 0$. You can write explicitly what this means.

Comment: I think I understand, so I need to find v such that $A^2v \neq 0$ ?

Comment: Yep. Explicitly, any $v = (x,y,z)^t$ with $z \neq 0$ works.